# Comparing IP addresses

Tags: php, ip

```
function getIp() {
  return "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>";
}
```

I want to adapt or redo this so that certain actions can only be taken from localhost or my isp server. I can make it work with a little bit of JavaScript for 127.0.0.1 but not for the other.

Appreciate any help; thanks

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this at all?  You should clarify your question.

Comment: And if the client has JavaScript disabled, then what? It looks like you're trying to implement some sort of security. This is not the way.

Comment: Don't foget to also check for `::1`.

Comment: Never use javascript to do the thing belong to server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really want to do this completely on the server. If you check for IPs on the client side then people can very easily hack around that. For example by modifying your code in their browser using a web inspector like Firebug.

Fortunately it is pretty simple to do on the server side:

The `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable is a simple string so you should be able to use string comparison to check for the IPs that you want.

Like for example:

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "1.2.3.4") {
       echo "Show secret things here";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks all, particularly St3fan. It works. I should explain what I am doing is not a software solution but a solution that uses software. My main concern is other parts but it seems to me I need to do some coding as a kind of performance spec for professional help.

Comment: The question title is "Comparing IP addresses". Note that string comparison in general is not a good idea to compare ip addresses! The reason is that there are multiple strings representing the same ip. For example, the IP `127.0.0.1` is equal to `127.000.000.001`, `127.00.000.1` or even `0:0:0:0:0:ffff:7f00:1` (as ipv6), just to name a few. You can only do string comparison if you know that your IP is in some kind of normalized format. It might be that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` does this (I have found nothing on that), but it might also depend on PHP version, operating system etc.

Comment: To be on the safe side, better use `if(ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) === ip2long("127.0.0.1"))` (only for ipv4).